MAUI.Net Binding
            <CollectionView Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Commands.Commands}">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type base:RelayCommand}">
                        <ImageButton Padding="0" CornerRadius="0" Command="{Binding Command}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>

If I write this Command Property: Command="{Binding Command}" I am getting the fallowing error at
compiletime:

The input string is in the wrong format.

But if i write it while i am debugging it's working. But can't recompile it.
removing the properties with binding let me compile the code.
writing the binding while debugging => works
i have the same problem here in the datagridtemplatecolumn
        <syncfusiondatagrid:SfDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Reminders}" SelectedRow="{Binding Selected}" AutoGenerateColumnsMode="None" AllowEditing="False"
                           AllowDeleting="False" AllowDraggingColumn="False"  ColumnWidthMode="Fill" BackgroundColor="White">
            <syncfusiondatagrid:SfDataGrid.Columns>
                <syncfusiondatagrid:DataGridTextColumn HeaderText="{DynamicResource name}" DisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <syncfusiondatagrid:DataGridTextColumn HeaderText="{DynamicResource started}" DisplayBinding="{Binding Started}"/>
                <syncfusiondatagrid:DataGridTextColumn HeaderText="{DynamicResource appointment}" DisplayBinding="{Binding Appointment}"/>
                <syncfusiondatagrid:DataGridTemplateColumn HeaderText="{DynamicResource remaining}" >
                    <syncfusiondatagrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type vm:ReminderViewModel}">
                            <syncprogressbar:SfLinearProgressBar  />
                            <!--Progress="{Binding Progress, Mode=OneWay}" Maximum="1" Minimum="0" Background="Transparent"
                                                             ProgressFill="{Binding Expired, Converter={StaticResource reminderprogressconverter}}"-->
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </syncfusiondatagrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </syncfusiondatagrid:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </syncfusiondatagrid:SfDataGrid.Columns>

        </syncfusiondatagrid:SfDataGrid>

the source is from this collection in my viewmodel
public class CommandCollection 
{
    public IEnumerable<RelayCommand> Commands=> collection;
    public string Name => ancestor.Name;

    private readonly IHierarchical ancestor;
    private readonly ObservableCollection<RelayCommand> collection = new ObservableCollection<RelayCommand>();
    public CommandCollection(IHierarchical ancestor)
    {
        this.ancestor = ancestor ?? throw ExceptionHandler.ArgumentNullException(this, nameof(ancestor));
    }
    public RelayCommand Register(Registration registration, bool enabled, bool async, string tag, string tooltip, Action<object> action, IObservable<bool> indicator = null)
    {
        RelayCommand command = RelayCommand.GenerateCommand(registration, enabled, async, tag, tooltip, action, indicator);
        collection.Add(command);
        return command;
    }
    public void Append(RelayCommand command) => collection.Add(command);
    public bool Remove(RelayCommand command) => collection.Remove(command);
}

if i remove the x:DataType it says: Binding Property Command not found on ...ToolViewModel -> DataType of the DataTemplate
here is the full Datatemplate
<DataTemplate x:Key="tooltemplate" x:DataType="{x:Type corevm:ToolViewModel}">
    <Grid ColumnSpacing="5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <Label Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource tokenconveter}}" FontSize="25"/>

        <CollectionView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Indicators.Collection}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Rectangle WidthRequest="2" VerticalOptions="Fill" Fill="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource indicatorconverter}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        
        <CollectionView Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Commands.Collection}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type base:RelayCommand}">
                    <ImageButton Padding="0" CornerRadius="0" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        
        <editors:SfComboBox Grid.Column="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Selectors}" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
                            IsClearButtonVisible="False" Padding="0" IsVisible="{Binding PageCount, Converter={StaticResource pagevisibilityconverter}}"
                            Background="{DynamicResource Gray950}" TextColor="White" DropDownBackground="{DynamicResource Gray950}"
                            DropDownItemTextColor="White" ShowBorder="False" DropDownStroke="{DynamicResource Gray600}">
        </editors:SfComboBox>

        <base:ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Item="{Binding Page}" DataTemplateSelector="{DynamicResource templateselector}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>


a RelayCommand does not have a property named Command

What is your intention with setting Type base:RelayCommand?

actually it does have this property, its my own implementation not the CommunityToolkit,
, my intetion is to have the nice xaml lookups
like i wrote if i add the line with the binding while debbuging it works like expected...

what is Commands.Commands

it looks like my BIndingContext is not the Item in the collection... how to fix that

For the ImageButton  inside CV, you need to set the  x:Name for the CollectionView like mCollectionView and the set Command="{Binding  Path= BindingContext.YourCommand,Source={Reference mCollectionView }}"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
